# Android Tab Text color

Tags: android, android-text-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Change Tab Text Color Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577688/android-change-tab-text-color-programmatically)

How can we change the text color in android tab.

Comment: The text color of what? You can use android:textColor on a TextView to set the color of text. A Tab must contain other views.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use following code

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
        { 
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        } 
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
```

Comment: ColorStateList is the better way

Answer (score 34):

I use the [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), find it more elegant. Here is an example :

tab_text.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/tab_active" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/tab_inactive" />
</selector>
```

In your TextView, just set the textColor to point to this file with  :

```
android:textColor="@color/tab_text"
```

Comment: This solution is much cleaner than the other posted solution

Comment: its working, this post is simple and state forward and its saved my time,thank you.