# How to Change swipe Tab Title color in java Android

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe

By Default, the View Pager(Swipe Tabs) Tab title color is White but i want to change into orange. Can any one help me please or share if you have any tutorial.

Thanks...

Comment: No sir I used TabLayout for Swipe Tabs, but i want to change title color of a Tab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7399342/2032561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style in your styles.xml and assign the style to your tab layout.

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
<item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyMaterialTheme.TabLayout.TextAppearance</item>
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.TabLayout.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_inactive</item>
<item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Check implementation from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

Comment: Thanks for giving me solution.